# Div contentEditable Focus Bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, focus, contenteditable

This is keyup function , the div contentEditable="true"

```
document.getElementById("text").onkeyup = function() {
    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = this.innerHTML.toUpperCase();   
}
```

The words are being uppacase but, cursor staying only first char.

But when I replace the value to img, the cursor is going to the first char.
İ didn't do any focus.
what is the solution?